# QResource unregisterResource returns always false

Tags: qt, qt5.7, rcc, qresource

I have a **problem registering/unregistering .rcc** files. I have several .qrc files (themes, for customization reasons) from which I create the coresponding .rcc files at build time. From the application the user should be able to **change the .rcc theme dynamically**. So for that, I had to do `QResource::unregisterResource(path/first.rcc)` and then `QResource::registerReousrce(path/second.rcc)`.

The **problem is** that **unregisterResource always returns false** and the application **resources appear to be mixed** in the views (some from the first.rcc, some from the second.rcc).

I use **QT 5.7**.

Do you have any suggestions? Why does unregisterResource return false? Thanks

Comment: Have you found any solution for that?

Comment: @RômuloM.Farias as I recall I didn't use anymore unregister. I had to change the way of loading .rccs. I just load the .rccs over the already loaded .rccs. But for unregistering I did not find a way

Comment: ok then, thank you anyway!

Comment: If someone pass by here with same problem, I've asked a related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43766738/qresource-unregister-rcc-files