# QResource: unregister .rcc files

Tags: c++, qt, qresource

We  have an application with multiple themes, whom calls other minor apps. So, on main app there is something like that:

```
// User opens app with theme A
QResource::registerResource("theme_a.rcc");      // returns TRUE

// User changes theme to B
QResource::unregisterResource("theme_a.rcc");    // returns TRUE
QResource::registerResource("theme_b.rcc");      // returns TRUE
```

Everything works fine on main application. The problem begins when this software calls other qt apps.

Inside those minor apps we follow the same flow of register and unregister. The weird part is that register always works and unregister never works (only inside minors apps). It's happening something like that:

```
// User opens app with theme A
QResource::registerResource("minor_theme_a.rcc");      // returns TRUE

// User changes theme to B
QResource::unregisterResource("minor_theme_a.rcc");    // returns FALSE
QResource::registerResource("minor_theme_b.rcc");      // returns TRUE
```

Why is it happening? Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unregisterResource` returns true if the resource is successfully unloaded **and** no references exist for the resource.

So in your case there could be still some more references from some other forms.

Important documentation with respect to `unregisterResource`:

***If there are QResources that currently reference resources related to the unregistered file, they will continue to be valid but the resource file itself will be removed from the resource roots, and thus no further QResource can be created pointing into this resource data. The resource itself will be unmapped from memory when the last QResource that points to it is destroyed.***

So my strong guess is some `QResource` is still pointing to the one that you tried to unregister.

Comment: It can be a newbie question but, how do I know that some QResource is pointing to what I'm unregistering? The only action that I take is call register and unregister. I don't have a qResource object, I just call the static methods...

Comment: Usually we can know if library can return reference count.... I will investigate a bit.... please try from your side too..

Comment: https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/io/qresource.cpp.html.... you can see the implementation of unregisterResource.. Search for "QResource::unregisterResource" in above link. They are using " QDynamicFileResourceRoot" to know about the further references. I do not think Qt expose this level of library classes. Or if you badly need it, you can create a wrapper class for registering an unregistering and maintain the count.

Comment: Yes I can see there. I don't think I'll create some wrapper to control that. I've just implemented the same logic flow in another sub app and it works fine. Somewhere in the code must be referencing resources in a bad way. I'll keep looking for that .... But thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the resources you wanna unregister are still pointed by QResource, the code below works for me to unregister successfully:

```
QQmlEngine::clearComponentCache();
QResource::unregisterResource(xxx/xxx.rcc);
```